# How to check the route table on a neighboring router?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, eigrp

I have a router in a network, which use to show list of routes in the route table.
Using the command-
`show ip eigrp topology`
I see some of the routes are removed after sometime, which were advertised from its neighbor.

I wanted to check whether the routes advertised by the neighbor have got removed from the neighbor as well.

I know the neighbor's IP address.

Is it possible for me to check the route table of the neighboring router?

Comment: what is a router model?

Comment: ASR1k  is the router model

Comment: could you please add configuration as well?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In cisco you can check neighbor devices which directly connected devices using

```
Show cdp neighbors
```

If you want more details

```
show cdp neighbor details.
```

In addition to that if you want to check route table you can use

```
show ip route
```

If you have configure `eigrp` you can use

```
show ip eigrp neighbors detail
```

Comment: Neither of which answers the question though, how to check the neighbors routing table, which cannot be done actually

Comment: @MattDouhan I understand it wrongly.